# PHP Installing browscap

Tags: php, windows, browser, ini, browscap

I can't get `get_browser()` to work.

I followed this tutorial about installing browscap : http://code18.blogspot.fr/2009/07/installer-browscapini-pour-php.html
But it didn't work for me. When i display PHP info, in the core section, browscap has "no value".

I added this in php.ini :

```
[browscap]
browscap = C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\php_browscap.ini
```

right before :

```
[Date]
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = UTC
```

I'm running a WAMP server on windows 7 x64.

Can anyone help please ? Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

Make a download from oficial [Browser Capabilities Project](http://tempdownloads.browserscap.com/)

Change php.ini

```
[browscap]
browscap = C:\..\php_browscap.ini
```

After, restart Apache